# Reading large text file line by line in Python

Tags: python, text

I'm trying to read a .txt file (output from terminal) into Python line by line. Here are the first few lines from the file:

```
new/2017_01_13_11_28_48_read_1062_reply_12_海鸥86_STRNAT_ADD.txt;new/2017_01_25_21_20_20_read_51_reply_0_尔乐乎_STRNAT_REG.txt;0%
new/2017_01_13_11_28_48_read_1062_reply_12_海鸥86_STRNAT_ADD.txt;new/2017_01_07_10_48_26_read_393_reply_1_自然向前_STRNAT_REG.txt;0%
new/2017_01_13_11_28_48_read_1062_reply_12_海鸥86_STRNAT_ADD.txt;new/2017_01_04_13_58_53_read_48_reply_0_外星人社会_STRNAT_REG.txt;0%
new/2017_01_13_11_28_48_read_1062_reply_12_海鸥86_STRNAT_ADD.txt;new/2017_01_31_23_07_06_read_743_reply_3_海堤梦言_STRNAT_REG.txt;0%
```

I understood that iterating over the lines is better than f.readlines(). When I run the below code, it seems to read it in okay, but the first line of the output is not the same as the first line of the file.

I've tried checking the encoding of the text file, and re encoding it as 'utf-8'. I have tried inspecting it for problems in a text editor. Here is my code:

```py
with open('/Users/nicholasolczak/Desktop/sherlock-master/results2.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line.strip())
f.close()
```

I expected it to print the file line by line. But first line of console output:

```
82_reply_1_世界公民。_STRNAT_Rnew/2017_01_26_22_19_46_read_13_reply_0_海鸥86_STRNAT_ADD.txt;new/2017_01_26_04_50_00_read_0_reply_0_NOAUT_RMW_REG.txt;0%
new/2017_01_26_22_19_46_read_13_reply_0_海鸥86_STRNAT_ADD.txt;new/2017_01_01_13_44_00_read_0_reply_0_NOAUT_RMW_REG.txt;0%
```

Would really appreciate any help. I'm new to this.

Comment: More as a side note: you don't need to do `f.close()` if you're using a context manager `with`

Comment: Which python version do you use?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this on mac os with python2 or 3. It worked as intended, so I'd guess that this has something to do with the file/unicode values of those chinese characters on your machine. If you're using python 3 its also worth trying a custom delimiter.

Comment: @Pynchia Python 3.7. Thanks!

Comment: @maverik thanks for your help. I'll try changing the file encoding, and also will look into a custom delimiter.

Comment: I tried adding a enumerate to the loop:
```python 
with open('/Users/nicholasolczak/Desktop/sherlock-master/results2B.txt') as f:
    for idx, line in enumerate(f):
        print(idx, line)
```
Output seems to start a long way into the text file? 

59_read_37_reply_0_海鸥86_STRNAT_REG.txt;0%

49646 new/2017_01_09_21_21_43_read_38_reply_0_国际频道_STRNAT_REG.txt;new/2017_01_03_08_42_00_read_0_reply_0_NOAUT_RMW_REG.txt;0%

Comment: Seems like it's just on the console it only prints some results - if I write output to a file it works.